# What is particle decay in condensed matter physics?

Tags: condensed-matter, fermions

What does it mean for a particle to decay in low energy quantum physics? To be more precise, let us consider either a fermionic Fock space $\mathscr{F}$ generated by a single-particle Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$. Let $|0\rangle$ denote the Fermi sea (ground state of the Fermi gas Hamiltonian $H_0=\sum \epsilon_k c_k^*c_k$). Now when I think of decay, I presume that we are talking about excited states, i.e., states with particles and holes added to the Fermi sea, which evolve as $e^{iH t} \psi \propto e^{-t/\tau} (\cdots) + (1-e^{-t/\tau})|0\rangle$ where $H=H_0+H_1$ and $H_1$ is some perturbative interaction term.

The question is that why is $e^{iH t}\psi \to |0\rangle$ true? If my understanding of "decay" is incorrect, please correct me.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the details in the specific context you're describing. But, in general, you can model decay using a non-Hermitian Hamiltonian operator. Then the energy spectrum is complex. The imaginary part of the energy eigenvalues are the inverse decay times. This kind of model arises by starting from a full system, and then averaging over some of the degrees of freedom. For instance, we can describe the process where a muon decays into an electron and two neutrinos using a Hermitian Hamiltonian with all particles, or we can use a non-Hermitian one with only the muon and electron.

Comment: I see. That also makes sense. I guess in that case could you elaborate or point to some references in which such a non-Hermitian operator arises from hermitian operators (possibly with examples in condensed matters)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Term *decay* is rather rare in condensed matter physics, so I will assume that what you really mean is the *finite lifetime*.

Condensed matter studies complex many-paryicle systems. For example, description of a crystal in terms of electron Bloch waves is valid only under assumption of a a rigid lattice and absence of Coulomb interaction. Once the interactions are taken into account, we end up with complex many-body states, which are usually interpreted in terms of*quasiparticles* (see my answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/604051/247642), for example) which may or may not be similar to fundamental particles studied in the relativistic QFT. In many cases they are similar - such as Landau quasiparticles in metals or "conduction electrons" and holes in semiconductors. However, not being the true eigenstates of the many-body Hamiltonian, these quasiparticles are unstable, i.e., with time they decompose (*decay*) into other excitations. This is just another way of saying that they have *finite lifetime*